# Docker Sail Laravel Postgresql - cannot connect to database container with application or tableplus

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker

I started a new Laravel 10 project using Sail. The project uses Postresql. I understand Sail creates the database when the container is first spun up.

I cannot connect to the database server (tells me 'connection refused')

My `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
#            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - laravel_test_sail
        depends_on:
            - pgsql
    pgsql:
        image: 'postgres:15'
        ports:
            - '${DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
        environment:
            PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
            POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/pgsql/create-testing-database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sql'
        networks:
            - laravel_test_sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - pg_isready
                - '-q'
                - '-d'
                - '${DB_DATABASE}'
                - '-U'
                - '${DB_USERNAME}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    caddy:
        build:
            context: "./Docker/Caddy"
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: "${WWWGROUP}"
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "${APP_PORT:-80}:80"
            - "${APP_SSL_PORT:-443}:443"
        environment:
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            HOST_DOMAIN: laravel.test
        volumes:
            - "./Docker/Caddy/file:/etc/caddy"
            - ".:/srv:cache"
            - "./Docker/Caddy/certificates:/data/caddy/certificates/local"
            - "./Docker/Caddy/authorities:/data/caddy/pki/authorities/local"
            - "sailcaddy:/data:cache"
            - "sailcaddyconfig:/config:cache"
        networks:
            - laravel_test_sail
        depends_on:
            - laravel.test
networks:
    laravel_test_sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-pgsql:
        driver: local
    sailcaddy:
        driver: local
    sailcaddyconfig:
        driver: local
```

My `.env` settings for the database are:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5632
DB_DATABASE=sail
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

When  I try and run `sail artisan migrate:fresh --seed` I get:

```
admin@DEV-PC:~/Projects/laravel_test$ sail artisan migrate:fresh --seed

  Dropping all tables ..................................................................................................................... 7ms FAIL

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

 SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select tablename, concat('"', schemaname, '"."', tablename, '"') as qualifiedname from pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname in ('public'))
```

My `pgsql` log in from Docker container is:

```
2023-03-13 10:51:39 2023-03-13 00:51:39.461 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-03-13 10:51:39 2023-03-13 00:51:39.461 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-03-13 10:51:39 2023-03-13 00:51:39.461 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-03-13 10:51:39 2023-03-13 00:51:39.463 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-03-13 10:51:39 2023-03-13 00:51:39.468 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-03-13 00:51:34 UTC
2023-03-13 10:51:39 2023-03-13 00:51:39.473 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-03-13 10:51:43 2023-03-13 00:51:43.607 UTC [33] FATAL:  database "sail" does not exist
2023-03-13 10:52:09 2023-03-13 00:52:09.541 UTC [41] FATAL:  database "sail" does not exist
2023-03-13 10:52:39 2023-03-13 00:52:39.675 UTC [50] FATAL:  database "sail" does not exist
2023-03-13 10:51:39 
2023-03-13 10:51:39 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2023-03-13 10:51:39 
2023-03-13 10:53:09 2023-03-13 00:53:09.804 UTC [58] FATAL:  database "sail" does not exist
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime you use Docker Compose, you must use the container's name as the HOST, so `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` should be `DB_HOST=pgsql` (the container's name), and, of course, the container trying to resolve the host should have the same network, in your case both containers (`laravel.test` consuming `pgsql`) have the same network defined.

Also, if you want to connect to any container (port) externally (from your local machine, not another container), you have to expose the desired ports, and you did so writting:

```yaml
ports:
  - '${DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
```

So, whatever GUI you use to externally (outside the container) connect to the database, use `127.0.0.1` and port `DB_PORT` (if you did not defined that in your environment or in `.env`, it will default to `5432`).

More info about `.env` and environment variables on a `docker-compose` file on the [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars-precedence/).

---

Because you are getting errors back from the database container, try running `docker compose down -v` (if `docker compose` errors, use `docker-compose`). That command will delete every container, and `-v` will delete each volume. So next time you do `docker compose up -d`, it will create every container again and re run "first time" scripts, so Postgres should create the desired database and not fail.

This is the official info about the `postgres` docker image, read the part about `POSTGRES_DB`: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: Hi @mattiaslauriti, moltissime grazie!